# Is there a word for "one who is spoken to"?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there an English word for "a person who is spoken to"? I guess you could say *speakee* or *talkee* or something but I'm looking for a word that's already well established.

Comment: _Addressee_ is the usual term in the trade for second-person referents.

Comment: You could use _listener_, although that implies that the person is actually listening, which you may or may not want to do.

Comment: I lean on *audience* a lot in IT documentation. "The audience for this procedure is..."

Comment: @JohnLawler That sounds like pretty close, but does *addressee* require that the person is actually *addressed*, i.e. mentioned by the speaker? If so, it's not quite exactly what I'm looking for, thought the difference is probably negligible in most situations.

Comment: The addressee in a written communication is not physically addressed by the writer. And many intended addressees are not physically addressed, even by spoken communication -- If I shout and you don't hear me, you're still the addressee (though not the recipient) of my shout.

Comment: @John Lawler is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The person being spoken to is often called the **listener**

Cambridge Learners Dictionary defines  a listener as **someone who listens**.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, user242899. Your answer would be improved by citing a dictionary.

Comment: Point taken.  New to this so I will next time. Thank you

Comment: @user242899 please take the first comment as a strong suggestion to _update and improve this answer._ Site policy, down-vote danger and all that.

Comment: Helpful? Not really.  'Someone who listens' is not identical to 'someone who is spoken to'; it might be discovered that one is trying to get through to a deaf person. Also, this is hardly suitable for a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: Suggest an alternative. I was under the impression this site was for English learners  not  just linguists. My brother is deaf and we say he listens to the TV. I went with what the asker wanted based on the clues in his question.  PS; cant see any other answers- so much for the linguists.